# Sending udp packets betwen 2 machines using nmap

Tags: udp, nmap

Im trying to learn so if im asking about something that doesnt make sense do tell me cause it probably doesnt.

I am trying to send udp packets between two machine. Im using my desktop and my latptop, both windows 11, on different ip adresses. I downloaded nmap to use ncat.

My expectation was to holepunch by sending several packages and eventually see some data be received by the other machine. From looking around i imagined i could do this the following way:

On each machine open one console to send udp with:
ncat -u [OtherMachineIp] -p 55999

On each machine open one console to to listen for incoming traffic on the port using:
ncat -lu -vvv 55999

Ive tried several alternative parameters and ive tried sending packets many times in a row. But no sign of anything arriving on the other side.

Im not sure what i should look for though. Is this even possible or am i doing something unreasonable?